# Problem in Chat Room-Search Bar

Tags: support, bug, chat

Some times when i click in the search bar when form is loading then the Hint Text does not get blank after loading completed. Even it allows to continue enter text after hint text. The forcolor also does not get black. There is no issue in searching room or user.

The following screenshot will shows the problem.

You can see the text is append after Hint Text in the search bar in this screenshot.
[image]

I have cleared all text then i have tried to enter text. But, it shows in gray color.
[image]

Comment: Look in your JavaScript console for errors.

Comment: @SecondRikudo I am not a web developer. But, i have checked it in my Chrome's Developer Tool->Console it shows a warning when i start to type in search bar.

`event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. in jquery.min.js:3`

Comment: And that happens when the issue occurs? Try refreshing the page.

Comment: This warning shows every first time after page load. I have reloaded page. its not working. I am getting this error from last 5 to 10 days.

Comment: This problem only occurs when the page is loading and i clicked in the search bar. Now my cursor is already in the box. When page is loaded completely the style of textbox will be set "watermark". It should not  be if cursor is already focused.

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: The problem is that it uses javascript instead of placeholder attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Exchange sites use jQuery. jQuery generally does not run before the page was loaded completely (on DOM ready).

Which is why, **JavaScript won't work until the page is completely loaded**. The problem should not return if you wait until the page is fully loaded (the spinner on tab disappears and the site's logo appears), before string to type.