# Chat room appears as text only without any styling

Tags: bug, design, chat, firewall

Most of the chat rooms I join appear to me as text only without any styling. Is this because of my company firewall?

Comment: Your browser console can tell you (F12 if you're on windows)

Comment: There are errors in the browser console - "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)" -- firewall issue?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the CSS stylesheet for Chat doesn't return a 403. So it is likely something in the network path between your browser and SE servers that returns that 403 instead of regular content.

Comment: What's interesting is that it only does it for some of the rooms - and not consistently. Weird.

Comment: in rare cases it might be that a small amount of users hit one of the nine webservers that is having a bad day, causing intermittent problems. I'm not sure if chat css files are delivered over fastly but then you can have the same intermittent issue when fastly is having problem. Those ae often very localized and shor-lived. And then there is ISPs, Corporate IT peeps, over-eager virus scanners that can throw things off the cliff.

Comment: Makes sense. The firewall I work behind is a Frankenstein configuration and allows/blocks sites and site parts at random. I'll just go ahead and blame my network. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eek! Chat FAQ formatting gone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227264/282094) https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224867/282094 or more likely: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85454/282094

Comment: Reopening, close voters missed the last part in the (non) dupe:  *This only happens on the https version of the page*. That's not relevant anymore. The reason here is clearly something on the OP side.